# AngularFire getIdToken(true) not refreshing token

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase-authentication, angularfire

I have an angularfire authentication service which works absolutely fine - except it wont refresh the token.

My refresh code:

```
firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(true).then((token: string) => {
    const newUser = { token: token }; // new user details in brief
    this.user.next(newUser);
});
```

calls the firebase service just fine and gives a response, but it only returns the current token and doesn't refresh the token - so it still logs out of the app after 1 hour.

I have read a multitude of issues regarding getIdToken but none which specifically address a token not refreshing.

I made a stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-uvcdz7?file=src/app/app.component.ts so you can see the code in full (though it doesn't work for some reason, but also because I cant work out how to connect the project to firebase via SB)

**edit**

To help there are some other odd behaviours I dont expect, for example in my ngOnInit I have...

```
this.fAuth.onAuthStateChanged((state) => {
    console.log(state);
})
```

which does nothing when I log in or out - no message to say the state has changed. None of these functions which I expect to trigger when things change in the authentication seem to do anything.

**edit 2**

As added info, before I added the bounty I did a full and painful update of Angular and AngularFire, so now Angular is v13 and AngularFire is 7.2.0 to see if this would make any difference, but it did not, the getIdToken still provides no refresh of the token.

**edit 3**

So this function was provided as an answer below:

```
public getToken$(): Observable<firebase.auth.IdTokenResult> {
    return from(this.fAuth.currentUser).pipe(switchMap(user => {
        return from(user.getIdTokenResult(true)).pipe(map(token => {
            console.log(token);
            return token;
        }));
    }));
}
```

which returns a user object:

{
"claims": {
"name": "Bogomip",
"picture": "piccie",
"admin": true,
"iss": "https://securetoken.google.com/repo",
"aud": "repo",
"auth_time": 1638464159,
"user_id": "user id",
"sub": "user id",
"iat": 1638464323,
"exp": 1638467923,
"email": "email@gmail.com",
"email_verified": true,
"firebase": {
"identities": {
"email": [
"email@gmail.com"
]
},
"sign_in_provider": "password"
}
},
"token": "THIS IS THE TOKEN",
"authTime": "Thu, 02 Dec 2021 16:55:59 GMT",
"issuedAtTime": "Thu, 02 Dec 2021 16:58:43 GMT",
"expirationTime": "Thu, 02 Dec 2021 17:58:43 GMT",
"signInProvider": "password",
"signInSecondFactor": null
}

this is the 'token' that is logged in that function, but is the token in this (token.token) the refresh id OR the actual token? Because it doesnt change, but that would make sense if it was the refresh token.... do we ever get to see the actual token?

Comment: Firebase handle the token refresh process, so there is no need to manually refresh the token.
Also, there is no need to use 'autoLogin', you can request firebase auth state with 'authState' property.
Also, there is no need to keep 'userData' in localStorage, you can read it from firebase =)

Comment: @MaxXx1313 if its read from firebase does angularfire store it locally? By storing it in localStorage I was hoping to keep it moving fast as opposed to consistently query the auth db everytime a guard fired off...

Comment: `shareReplay(1)` keeps the value in memory, so there is only one request to `authState`, and the changes in auth state are populated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force refresh the token using Observables this way:

```
public getToken$(): Observable<firebase.auth.IdTokenResult> {
  return from(this.angularFireAuth.currentUser).pipe(switchMap(user => {
    return from(user.getIdTokenResult(true)).pipe(map(token => {
      return token;
    }));
  }));
}
```

Comment: thanks Raymond but this doesn't seem to change the token, if I call this function I get the standard user info back with the same token every time (that's what your 'token' is here, all the user info)... is the token in that result  (so token.token in your function) the refresh token or the user token? If it was the refresh token that would make sense, but then how do you read the regular token, or cant you?

Comment: see edit3 on the main post...

Comment: I see ok, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Firebase handle the token refresh process, so there is no need to manually refresh the token. Firebase auth state can be read from 'authState' property.

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthenticationService implements OnInit {

  public readonly userId$: Observable<string>;

  public readonly profile$: Observable<MyProfile>;


  constructor(
    public firestore: AngularFirestore,
    public fAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    private router: Router,
  ) {

    this.userId$ = this.fAuth.authState.pipe(
      map(fbUser => fbUser ? fbUser.uid : null),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      tap(uid => {
        console.log('AuthService: userId$', uid);
      }),
      shareReplay(1),
    );


    this.profile$ = this.authService.userId$.pipe(
      switchMap(authId => {
        if (authId) {
          return this.getById(authId);
        } else {
          return EMPTY;
        }
      }),
      tap(profile => {
        console.log('[AuthService] profile$', profile);
      }),
      shareReplay(1),
    );
  }

  public getById(id: string): Observable<MyProfile> {
    return this.firestore.doc<MyProfile>('users/'+id).get();
  }

}
```

Comment: But it isn't automatically refreshing the token - if I dont try and force it, it will just stop working anyway, the token becomes invalid and it stops allowing the user to access the database...

Comment: I think 'logout' issue may be related to 'autoLogout' functionality or loading 'userData'. For example, there is no way to cancel the logout timer, so if page is not reloaded, the timer will fire up eventually and log you out.

Comment: Even with the auto logout disabled it will not refresh the token... what do you mean with respect to the loading userData being a problem?